# For a given interface, I have three implementations. How the three implementation share a same method?

Tags: go

I have an interface:

```
type Reader interface {
    // Read IV and Master header
    ReadMaster(p []byte, full bool) (int, error)

    // Read User header
    ReadUser(p []byte, full bool) (int, error)

    // Read Content data
    ReadContent(p []byte) (int, error)
}
```

And I have three `struct`s are compatible with the interface. All the three structs have the samve method `ReadUser`. So I have to do:

```
func (r *s1) ReadUser(buf []byte, full bool) (int, error) {
//.... code 1 ....
}
func (r *s2) ReadUser(buf []byte, full bool) (int, error) {
//.... code 2 ....
}
func (r *s3) ReadUser(buf []byte, full bool) (int, error) {
//.... code 3 ....
}
```

However, the "code1", "code2" and "code3" above are exactly the same. It's there a good way to reduce the duplicate codes? E.g. define the function once and assign it to three struct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in its own type. Remembering too that interfaces in Go should only provide contracts for small specific tasks. It is very common for an interface to contain only a single method.

```
type UserReader interface {
    ReadUser(p []byte, full bool) (int, error)
}

type UserRepo struct {
}
```

Add the method to that type:

```
func (ur *UserRepo) ReadUser(p []byte, full bool) (int, error) {
    // code to read a user
}
```

Then, embed it in your other types:

```
type s1 struct {
    *UserRepo
    // other stuff here..
}

type s2 struct {
    *UserRepo
    // other stuff here..
}

type s3 struct {
    *UserRepo
    // other stuff here..
}
```

Then you can:

```
u := s1{}
i, err := u.ReadUser(..., ...)

u2 := s2{}
i2, err2 := u2.ReadUser(..., ...)

// etc..
```

..and you can also do:

```
doStuff(u)
doStuff(u2)
```

.. where `doStuff` is:

```
func doStuff(u UserReader) {
    // any of the three structs
}
```

<kbd>[Click here to see it in the Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/CC2bH4eWJZ)</kbd>